# Functional-analysis. Show that the distance $p(x,y)$ satisfies the following properties.

Tags: functional-analysis

In a normed space, we can introduce the distance between any two of its elements by the formula $p(x,y) = ||x - y||$.
How can I show that the distance $p(x,y)$ satisfies the following properties:

> 1) $p(x,y) \geq 0$. In this case $p(x,y) = 0$, if and only if $x = y$;
>
> 2) $p(x,y) = p(y, x)$;
>
> 3) $p(x,y) \leq p(x,z) + p(z,y)$;

Comment: The three properties quite easily follow from the three properties in the definition of a norm. I am sure you can figure out the rest for yourself.

Comment: If I could, I don't ask this question.

Comment: How do you define $||x||$?

Comment: A-priory ||x|| is Nonnegative number. I don't know how can i define ||x|| correctly. Can you explain me, please?

Comment: Can you list the 3 properties of a norm? For example one of the properties is called definiteness, this property alone suffices to prove 1), can you see the connection?

Comment: Yes, I can. 1) ||x|| = 0, if x = 0; 2) ||lambda*x|| = ||lambda|| * ||x|| 3) ||x+y||<=||x||+||y||; ||x|| is nondegeneracy of the norm. Am I right? Unfortunately, i can't see connections and I would like to understand these notion.

Comment: Your property 1) should be $\|x\|=0$ if and _only if_ $x=0$.  Furthermore, another property is that $\|x\|≥0$ for all $x$. Can you see why the last thing I said implies $p(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ must be $≥0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A norm $\|\cdot\|:V\to \Bbb R$ is a function on (real or complex) a vector space $V$ that satisfies the following properties:

> 1. Positivity and definiteness: $\|x\|≥0$ for all $x\in V$. $\|x\|=0$ if and only if $x=0$.
> 2. Homogeneity: For any $\lambda\in\Bbb K$ ($\Bbb K$ is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, depending on whether we are looking at a real or a complex vector space) and any $x\in V$ you have $\|\lambda\, x\|=|\lambda|\,\|x\|$.
> 3. Sub-additivity: For any $x,y\in V$ you have $\|x+y\|≤\|x\|+\|y\|$.

Here are some hints on how to show the properties you are interested in:

1. $p(x,y)=\|x-y\|$, if you know that $\|\cdot\|$ applied to *any* vector is $≥0$, how does this help you show $p(x,y)≥0$ for any $x,y\in V$?

   Further, suppose $p(x,y)=\|x-y\|=0$. You know from definiteness of the norm that the only vector that has norm $0$ is $0$. How does this imply $x=y$?
2. $p(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ and $p(y,x)=\|y-x\|=\|-(x-y)\|$. Can homogeneity help you in showing these expressions are equal?
3. $p(x,y)=\|x-y\|=\|(x-z)+(z-y)\|$, whereas $p(x,z)+p(z,y)=\|x-z\|+\|z-y\|$. As you likely guessed, you need to apply sub-additvity of the norm somehow to get the result.